# Non Rectangular Images

Tags: image, image-processing

I am not sure if this question suits stackoverflow or not. But here it goes, I want to have an image strictly of the shape and size of the main object in the image, there should not be any white or black background, or the background should be transparent so that the real background should be visible. How can I do it? is it possible using photoshop? I want to use these images to create a slideshow in flash.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by creating an image with transparent background in Photoshop.

Comment: will that transparent background remain transparent when I add the image to the flash slide show?

Comment: That depends on the flash application, it needs to have transparent background as well.

Comment: Can you tell me any software that can create such a slide show for me? Please note I don't know action script, so far I am using bannersnack.com for creating a slide show but it is adding a rectangular background to the images automatically.

Comment: I don't know of any, but I think you can do it with most tools for creating flash files. Try setting the "background color", "stage background" or "stage color" or something similar.

Comment: I have tried using many softwares but as soon as I publish the file as swf, a background is added.. I am having no way to do what i want.

Comment: The entire stage background can't be transparent; then it would show through to your desktop's screen!

Comment: I understand that @WendiKidd ...
All I want is that I am using PNG images, that have images of, for example an Icecream, I want that only icecream should be visible and rest of the image should be transparent. I have such images, I have created a marquee in HTML and its perfect, but when I create an swf slide show, its ruined. There appears a rectangular box, a black box, surrounding the image.

Answer (score -1):

use transparent images and save it e.g. as png

Comment: i used such images, png, but when i use photosnack.com, or any other software to build a slide show in swf, the transparent portion of the image is colored black, destroying all the effect!